# SPARQL: Querying the Default Graph

Tags: sparql, rdf, allegrograph, named-graphs

With the RDF query language SPARQL, I'm trying to find a way to do a boolean query (or any other query) for anything not in a Named Graph.

```
ASK { GRAPH null { ?s ?p ?o } }
```

Can't find really any documentation on searching specifically within an empty Named Graph. Also tried replacing `null` with `<>`, `empty`, and  (nothing).

Comment: `ASK  { ?s ?p ?o }` is not working as expected? What is your triplestore?

Comment: I'm using Allegrograph 6.1.5. The problem I'm seeing with that query is that it returns True if a triple exists within a specific Named Graph as well.

Comment: Try `ASK { GRAPH DEFAULT { ?s ?p ?o } }`. If it is not working, then is `SELECT FROM DEFAULT {?s ?p ?o}` returns what you need?

Comment: And perhaps you could just add `PREFIX franzOption_defaultDatasetBehavior: <franz:rdf>` in the beginning of your original query.

Comment: Thanks! `SELECT * FROM DEFAULT {?s ?p ?o}` worked for querying an empty named graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query will look for triples in the default graph, then remove ones that are also in a named graph:

```
SELECT ?s ?p ?o {
   ?s ?p ?o 
   FILTER NOT EXISTS { GRAPH ?g { ?s ?p ?o } }
}
```